# Can I can use Java to do"Seeking 1 + 2 ! + 3 ! + ... + 20 ! And"?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this error：sum=-1490928446.You see:negative number.But I do not know what?I
define Summation and a,I hope It can Compute"1 + 2 ! + 3 ! + ... + 20 ! ".I think my code has no problem,but it tell me negative number.Why?How can I solve it.Thank you very much.Here is my source code：

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //And to define a number of statistics accumulated result
    int sum=0;
    //An alternative definition of variable
    int a=1;
   //Two for loop
    for(int j=1;j<21;j++)
    {   
      for(int i=1;i<j+1;i++)
     {
        a=a*i;  
       sum +=a;
      }

     }
     //Print output results
    System.out.println("sum="+sum);
}
```

}

I want to know what logical error?Thank you very much.

Comment: Try using `long` or `BigInteger`

Comment: There is another mistake in your code, `a` should be initialized inside the outermost loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you're overflowing the size of `int`. Changing to `long` can handle up to 20, but it will overflow too at any higher value, at which point you'd need `BigInteger`.

*However,* you have much bigger problems than that.
Your main problem is that your algorithm is bad.

You're supposed to be calculating this:

```
1 + 2 ! + 3 !    + 4 !          + 5 !                     + ...
1 + 1*2 + 1*2*3  + 1*2*3*4      + 1*2*3*4*5               + ...
1 + 2   + 6      + 24           + 120                     + ...
```

So let's add some print statements to see what you're *really* doing. See updated code and output below.

```
1 + 1+2 + 2+4+12 + 12+24+72+288 + 288+576+1728+6912+34560 + ...
```

*WOW!* That's not even close to the same thing.

I'll leave it to you to figure out where you went wrong.<sup>1</sup>
Those print statements will help with that.
     <sup>*1) Hint: Remove `i` loop.*</sup>

*Code*

```
int sum = 0;
int a = 1;
System.out.printf("              a=%-11d   sum=%d%n", a, sum);
for (int j = 1; j < 21; j++) {
    for(int i=1;i<j+1;i++) {
        a = a * i;
        sum += a;
        System.out.printf("j=%-2d   i=%-2d   a=%-11d   sum=%d%n", j, i, a, sum);
    }
}
System.out.println("sum=" + sum);
```

*Output*

```
              a=1             sum=0
j=1    i=1    a=1             sum=1
j=2    i=1    a=1             sum=2
j=2    i=2    a=2             sum=4
j=3    i=1    a=2             sum=6
j=3    i=2    a=4             sum=10
j=3    i=3    a=12            sum=22
j=4    i=1    a=12            sum=34
j=4    i=2    a=24            sum=58
j=4    i=3    a=72            sum=130
j=4    i=4    a=288           sum=418
j=5    i=1    a=288           sum=706
j=5    i=2    a=576           sum=1282
j=5    i=3    a=1728          sum=3010
j=5    i=4    a=6912          sum=9922
j=5    i=5    a=34560         sum=44482
j=6    i=1    a=34560         sum=79042
j=6    i=2    a=69120         sum=148162
j=6    i=3    a=207360        sum=355522
j=6    i=4    a=829440        sum=1184962
j=6    i=5    a=4147200       sum=5332162
j=6    i=6    a=24883200      sum=30215362
j=7    i=1    a=24883200      sum=55098562
j=7    i=2    a=49766400      sum=104864962
j=7    i=3    a=149299200     sum=254164162
j=7    i=4    a=597196800     sum=851360962
j=7    i=5    a=-1308983296   sum=-457622334
j=7    i=6    a=736034816     sum=278412482
j=7    i=7    a=857276416     sum=1135688898
```

Here you can also see your overflow problem occurring (the first time) at `j=7, i=5`.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is not enough. Highest value into `int` (32 bit) can be `2^31 -1`, that means 2147483647. Your sum is exceeding this. Use `long` instead.

```
long sum = 0;
long a = 1;
for (int j = 1; j < 21; j++) {
    for (int i = 1; i < j + 1; i++) {
        a = a * i;
        sum += a;
    }
}
System.out.println("sum=" + sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

`int` is 32 bits, meaning it can only hold so much. The range is `-2^31 ~ 2^31-1` to be exact. Per [Integer Overflow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) from Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is too large to be represented within the available storage space.

You're result is too large that it's overflowing and is giving you a negative result. Use a `long` which is 64 bits. Try this:

```
long sum = 0L;
long a = 1L;
```

Comment: Sure @ScaryWombat, don't know the number off the top of my head but the range I know (in exponential notation)

Answer (score 0):

int in Java has a range from +2,147,483,647 to -2,147,483,648. If your output exceeds this range, you can use long which has a range from +9,223,372,036,854,775,807 to -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.

If your output is even bigger than that, then try using the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). But in your case long would be enough to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code.
I think you should initialize `a` in the inner loop.
Also as soon as the Factorial sum exceeds the maximum integer values it starts from negative.So use `long`.

Following code should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long sum = 0;       

    for (int j = 1; j < 21; j++) {
        long a = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < j + 1; i++) {
            a = a * i;
        }
        sum += a;
        /*//checks when the sum exceeds the Maximum int value
         * if(sum>Integer.MAX_VALUE){ System.out.println(sum+"---->"+j); }
         */
    }

    System.out.println("sum=" + sum);
}
```